# having trouble with finding multiple roots of a system of equations with scipy fsolve

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods

Having a system of two coupled equations as below:

```
two_exponential = lambda x, kernel, c: np.array([x[0] - np.exp(kernel[0] * x[0] + kernel[2] * x[1] + c), x[1] - np.exp(kernel[1] * x[1] + kernel[3] * x[0] + c)])
```

I want to find the intersections of the two lines with `scipy.fsolve`.
The way I'm doing this is to find the roots of this system for different configurations of `b11,b22, b12, b21`.

```
b = np.array([b11, b22, b12, b21])
x_min_plot = -10
x_max_plot = 35
x_1 = np.linspace(x_min_plot, x_max_plot, 100)
x_2 = np.linspace(x_min_plot, x_max_plot, 100)
x_1, x_2 = np.meshgrid(x_1, x_2)
z_1 = -x_1 + np.exp(b[0] * x_1 + b[2] * x_2 + c)
z_2 = -x_2 + np.exp(b[1] * x_2 + b[3] * x_1 + c)
x_sols = []
x_min = 0
x_max = 35

for x in np.arange(x_min, x_max, 5):
    for y in np.arange(x_min, x_max, 5):
        initial = np.array([x, y])
        x_sol = fsolve(two_exponential, initial, args=(b, c), full_output=1)
        if x_sol[2] == 1: # if the solution converged
            x_sols.append(np.round(x_sol[0], 2))
# [x for i, x in enumerate(x_sols) if not np.isclose(x, x_sols[i-1], atol = 1e-1).all()]
x_sols = np.unique(x_sols, axis=0)


print(f'z*: {np.round(x_sols, 2)}')
if x_sol[2] != 1:
    print('no solution')
```

I also round the solutions to ignore the duplicated roots as I want to find only unique ones.
The code seems to work ok for some conditions:

[image]

But not for some other conditions:

[image]

Do you have an idea where can such a problem appear from?

Comment: Reduce the error tolerances. The method will stop when the approximation is good enough, which might can go wrong if the graph is shallow in the region-of-interest.

Comment: It is possible to eliminate one of the unknowns X1 or X2 to obtain a univariate equation.

Comment: Note that in your two examples, the solutions are close to the asymptotes. So their intersections could make good initial approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I achieved to overcome the problem with a simple trick. Since the fsolve method is finding the system's roots, inputting back the solutions to the function should result in zero. I add another if statement and checked if the solutions are actually resulted in zero and only accept those solutions.

```
if x_sol[2] == 1: # if the solution converged
   if np.isclose(two_exponential(x_sol[0], b, c), 0, atol = 1e-3).all():
```

And that solved the problem. I need to mention that the problem still remains and I don't know why fsolve does this. I changed the "[xtol](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)" in fsolve

but that's not helping much. Anyway, for now the problem is solved by checking if the roots are actually roots!